# Correct way to get environment variables and go through SonarLint

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a problem reading my environment variables and satisfying SonarLint(detect and fix quality issues) at the same time ..
That way it does not work my variable is null

```
 private String accessKey;
 @Value("${bws.access.key}")
public void setAccessKey(String ak){
    accessKey=ak;
}
```

Changing the method to static (as the sonarLint recommends) does not work the variable continuous null

```
private static String accessKey;
  @Value("${bws.access.key}")
public static void setAccessKey(String ak){
    accessKey=ak;
}
```

The only way I found to work is to mark the instance variable as static but not to mark the method as static

```
private static String accessKey;
  @Value("${bws.access.key}")
public void setAccessKey(String ak){
    accessKey=ak;
}
```

But there sonarLint points out the issue
**Instance methods should not write to "static" fields**

Is not this way I'm getting my enviroment variables across the boundaries not the right one?

Comment: Can you please add the code that uses the class that is holding the accessKey member. Especially the creation of the instance you used to check whether accessKey is set or not would be of interest.

Comment: I use within a method in the same class
headers.add ("ACCESSKEY", accessKey);

Comment: If your class is correctly wired by spring and not manually created (e.g. with `new MyClass()`), the first snippet should work correctly. I can only imagine that you get the described problems due to creating the bean manually. That is why I'm asking for the code that creates the bean instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code:

A Configuration Class (annotated with `@Component` in order to be picked up by Spring) which will hold the values coming from the properties file, where you bind the value of `bws.access.key` to a property directly. And if you need accessor methods for `accessKey` you can just create them (`setAccessKey` and `getAccessKey`)

```
@Component
public class ConfigClass {

    // @Value("${bws.access.key:<no-value>}")  // <- you can use it this way if you want a default value if the property is not found
    @Value("${bws.access.key}")                // <- Notice how the property is being bind here and not upon the method `setAccessKey`
    private String accessKey;

    // optional, in case you need to change the value of `accessKey` later
    public void setAccessKey(String ak){
        this.accessKey = ak;
    }

    public String getAccessKey() {
        return this.accessKey;
    }

}
```

For more details checkout this [GitHub sample project](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/valuedemo).

I tested this with

- IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5 (Ultimate Edition),Build #IU-181.5281.24
- SonarLint [image]

---

**(*Edit*) How to use it in a Controller**:

An option (there are others) could be to declare a constructor for the controller (let's call it `SampleController`) and request a parameter of type `ConfigClass` inside it. Now we set a controller attribute (`config`) of the same type to the value received as parameter, like this:

```
@RestController
public class SampleController {

    private final ConfigClass config;

    public SampleController(ConfigClass configClass) { // <- request the object of type ConfigClass
        this.config = configClass; // <- set the value for later usage
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "test")
    public String test() {
        return config.getAccessKey();  // <- use the object of type ConfigClass
    }
}
```

Now, Spring Boot will try to find a component (of any type) in the app of type `ConfigClass` and since we have one defined it will automatically inject it in our controller. This way you can set the parameter controller property `config` to the value received in `configClass` for later usage.

In order to test it, you can request the url `test`. You will see that the output will be `anotherValue`. So we can conclude that the Dependency Injection Mechanism successfully found an instance of `ConfigClass` and the method `ConfigClass#getAccessKey` works properly.

Comment: I do not understand, what is the function of the set method since the information I need comes from the environment variables and the properties?
bws.access.key = $ {BWS_ACCESSKEY}

Comment: @Manzini It is completely optional. I stated in the question _if you need accessor methods for `accessKey`_. So it is useful in case you need to change the value of `accessKey` later, but, again, you can get rid of it in case you don't need it. I posted it for completeness only.

Comment: @Manzini I added a comment above the method in order to make things clearer.

Comment: thanks for the patience, I'm new with springboot, I've seen that your posted solution works perfectly. Could you give me an example of how to use the method with the bean annotation in my controller class I tried using Autowired but I could not

Comment: You're welcome! If this was useful to you, please [upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/why-should-i-upvote-a-question) this question for future readers and consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it if you think it is the best one for your question. On the other hand I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean with _... how to use the method with the bean annotation in my controller class..._. Do you want to use the code (I posted as example in the github repo) inside the `CommandLineRunner` Bean in a controller of yours?

Comment: so I need to get the value of that variable accesskey to use it in the header of my post headers.add ("ACCESSKEY", getAccessKey ()); // here
I saw in your example but I could not use it correctly ... I created a Config class like yours, I wrote the method getAccesKey as Bean but how do I use this method in my controller?

Comment: Ho, I get it now. While `@Autowire` should work, it is now always true. That's why the Spring team recommends not to use it. I'll update the github repo and I'll let you know with an example.

Comment: @Manzini, please, check the answer updated (the part below _(Edit) How to use it in a Controller_) and the code in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/valuedemo) updated in order to see how to use it inside a controller.

Comment: Thank you so much, my friend, taught me a lot today!